# How to add a custom input filter to Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2, and I have created a new input filter that will be used throughout my application. I know that I need to add the new filter to the FilterPluginManager's list so that I can call it when I create inputs. This is the code that I believe I need to use:

```
\Zend\Filter\FilterPluginManager::setInvokableClass('myFilter', 'Namespace\Filters\MyFilter');
```

However, I can't find where this should go. Should this be in the bootstrap, or one of the config files, or somewhere else?

Comment: I haven't done this myself, but perhaps [this thread](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/ZF2-create-custom-filter-td4657029.html) will help. It has an example of adding it in a module's `onBootstrap()` method. Since you will be using it throughout your application, an option could be to do that in a base module. I would _think_ that it's possible to do it in a config file, but I am unfortunately not aware of how to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately that thread ends with the poster not being able to find a way to add the custom filter. I tried the methods suggested but the filter doesn't seem to be getting added.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer you want

https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html

```
class Module
{
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
           'UserInputFiler' => 'SomeModule\InputFilter\User',
        ),

    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Module`, implement `InputFilterProviderInterface` and provide a `Factory` for the `InputFilterPluginManager` (`AbstractPluginManager`):

```php
namespace YourModule; 

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class Module implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function getInputFilterConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories'=>[
                'your_input_filter_name'=>\YourModule\Factories\InputFilterFactory::class
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Now implement the factory:

```php
namespace YourModule\Factories;

use Zend\Filter\StringTrim;
use Zend\InputFilter\Input;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Validator\StringLength;

class InputFilterFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $filter = new InputFilter();
        $nameFilter = new Input("name");
        $nameFilter->getValidatorChain()->attach(new StringLength([
            'min'=>3,
            'max'=>16
        ]));
        $nameFilter->getFilterChain()->attach(new StringTrim());
        $filter->add($nameFilter);
        return $filter;
    }
}
```

Now in your `Controller`-factory or other factory where you need the `InputFilter` you can access the `InputFilterPluginManager`:

```php
$inputFilterManager = $controllerManager->getServiceLocator()->get('InputFilterManager');

return new YourController(
    $inputFilterManager->get('your_input_filter_name')
);
```

### Update, you can also add the factory to the module.config.php

```php
    'input_filters'=>[
        'factories'=>[
            'your_input_filter_name'=>InputFilterFactory::class
        ]
    ],
```